# error 'function' object has no attribute 'objects' when i try to create a record in the model in veiws.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to create a record in the register model immediately after creating user
But unfortunately, an error
'function' object has no attribute 'objects'
shows me

**views.py code:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import userregister
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from testapp.models import register

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = userregister(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            User.objects.create_user(cd['username'],cd['email'],cd['password'])
            register.objects.create(address='NONE' , phone = 'NONE' ,username_id= cd['id'])
            return redirect('testapp:index')
    else:
        form = userregister()

    context = {'form' : form}
    return render(request,'register.html',context)
```

**models.py code**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class register(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    username = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__ (self):
        return str(self.username)
```

I want to create a record in the register model immediately after the user is added, with the value NONE and the foreign key should be the same user as the one created now.

Comment: its because you are using same name for your Model class and your view function. Change your model to `class Register(models.Model)` and use `Register.objects...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good practice to name same your model and view name so kindly change model name to `Register` as it is written in `PascalCase` and the view name can be remain same or change to `register_view`.